# Display Wordpress loop with first item formatted differently?

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

I have a series of posts in a custom post type.  They each have a featured image (thumbnail)and an excerpt.

I want to display 4 items on the home page, with the first item formatted differently from the other 3, such as in the attached image.  How is that done?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a counter for this. See sample below

```
 <?php
  $inc = 1;
  $the_query = new WP_Query();
  $the_query->query("posts_per_page=4");
  if ($the_query->have_posts()) : 
  while($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();
  if($inc == 1){ 
   //first post here
   //do stuffs here
  }
 else{
  //the rest of the posts
 }

 $inc++; //counter
 endwhile; 
 endif; 
 wp_reset_postdata();
 ?>
```

Comment: Nice and simple.  I love it.  Thanks!

Comment: you can use `$the_query->current_post` to see the post INDEX. This way, no need to create a counter.

Comment: This is great. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The global `$wp_query` contains everything about the current query, including the arguments, results, contents of the results and the query itself.

You want to check `$wp_query->current_post` and if it is 0 then it is the first post of the loop.

```
if ( $wp_query->current_post === 0 ) {
    // first post
} else {
    // the rest
}
```

However, if you have many posts and pagination then the first post of every page will have index 0.

If you want to target the first post of the first page only then:

```
if ( $wp_query->current_post === 0 && $wp_query->query_vars['paged'] === 0 ) {
    // first post in first page only
} else {
    // the rest
}
```

A one-liner would be:

```
$class = ( $wp_query->current_post === 0 ) ? ' first_item' : '';
```

Then add `$class` to your item wrapper so you can style the first item in your CSS.